# Script# and attaching jQuery Events

Tags: script#

I am using Script# 0.6 and its newly added jQuery support, so far I am very impressed.

In the C# I attach a click handler to a button like so

```
jQuery.Select("#myButton").Click(myHandler);
```

And it gets compiled into this JavaScript

```
$("#myButton").click(ss.Delegate.create(this, this.myHandler));
```

Is there anyway to get it compiled into

```
$("#myButton").click(this.myHandler);
```

Or even better

```
$("#myButton").click($.proxy(this.myHandler, this));
```

I realise that this is a minor issue but I would like to reduce the number of references to `ss` and other Script# dependencies since Script# is still in its early stages of development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally ss.Delegate.create(this, this.myHandler) is very different from this.myHandler. They provide different behavior. The former preserves the "this" object context, and the latter doesn't.

If your handler doesn't need the "this" context, i.e. in c# terms, can be a static method, then make it so, and script# will emit the following instead:

```
$("myButton").click(MyClass.myHandler)
```

Hope that helps.

There is no way to replace what gets generated, but you can (if you really want) write your own version of mscorlib.js or ss.Delegate - the compiler doesn't care, as long as your implementation matches the contract it expects from the runtime script.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I guess the other option would be to write my own jQuery bridge, but for now the current implementation is fine. Keep up the great work.